# How to manage many highspeed client-server autonomus connections and remote programme execution

Tags: python, mysql, network-programming, client-server, network-security

Here is an interesting problem. I am building an application in AI, that is due to be fundamentally agnostic to computational architectures(hopefully to include mobile). We have built a python application with a machine learning and deep-learning data structure that connects to despaired systems, and combines data with the new systems usually running a windows app/sometimes mac. 
We have been working with net-workers and pen testers to determine the best approach to maintaining multiple client-server connections with asynchronicity and a heavy load, and maintain a positive security posture.

Here are the Upside's: 
  1. Data from the producers is very fast.
  2. Programmatically we have increased the ability to load-balance.

The downsides:
  1. The controllers / are not very fast. Here we are using languages (Node.js, go-Lang, cherrypy, rabbitmq) to speed up the connections and multi/Hyper thread. (Raspberry pi). Our goal is to use minimal frameworks pizero, raspberry, Arduino, to install and use our tech in an "instance" (See Tony Stark in avengers, connect the chips to the rail and create a command center). 
    2.point machines are not always quick, AND networking can suck. Using some fabric (with some hopes and dreams) we are nearly to the point of being able to deploy a system in seconds. Currently, data is slow on the back-end, and DB's are not helping that case. Some of our clients would like to test, and we are not interested in making a massive distro. With the amount of data, we only hope to achieve a "lightweight" client application that will leverage (dissimilar) technologies.

3. as we connect to "permanent" despaired systems we will pass our computational loads, and use for cold storage.

-We are having issues with application persistence / Surviving reboot
-With the multi-client control, commands are getting dropped.(some get them 2 times +)
-We are running many scripts and programs that get, write, read, put. We have them spread between multiple languages with all different uses and requirements.
- After the application is loaded updates are not always making it to each unit.

Thank you to all whom reply

Comment: Ok... so what's the question?

Comment: 1. What is the best way to survive reboot?

Comment: 2. What is the best way to package our exe into 1 standalone with no extra dependencies.                          3. we need the application to not be destroyed by the system or user.

Comment: What type of connections are you establishing with your clients? Examples are: `HTTPS`, `WebSocket`, `TLS but not HTTPS` , `DTLS`.

Comment: Websockets, HTTPS